# Where could I change formatting posts in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Where could I change formatting posts in Wordpress?
Explanation:
I want to make my own slideshow with button, so I need the uid of the image to make an url of that button.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's up on your theme. You have to find the "postfile".php and their associated css. Then if you could change formatting of your posts. 
I suggest you to read in codex wordpress [Know more about wordpress system](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types).

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I don't want that. So the content of the post is handled by `the_content` and the `the_content` has some array which contains text , images and ... and I want to modify formatting of that array

Comment: Could you paste the code snippet to see what you want to modify ?